# system.LinQ.Iqueryable(of date) cannot be converted to date

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to fetch data using linQ as shown below.

```
dim rerun as datetime

     Dim q = (From a In dashboard Where a.SucessFlag = 0 And a.ApplicationID = 1 _
                            Select a.logDate)
                rerunDate = q
```

I am getting this system.LinQ.Iqueryable(of date) cannot be converted to date

Any workaround will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect just one result just use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) to get the date. If you want the first result you can use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx).